# How can I define scope for plotting graph in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am now trying to plot dataframe by Pandas. Everything is good but I don't know how can I define y and x-axis scales. For example, in the following, I want to show the graph with from 1.0 to 0.0 in terms of y-axis scale instead of 0.0 to 0.7.

[image]

Here is the code for the above graph.

```
In [90]: df
Out[90]: 
             history       lit   science    social  accuracy
2014-11-18  0.680851  0.634146  0.452381  0.595745      0.01
2014-12-10  0.680851  0.634146  0.452381  0.595745      0.01

In [91]: df.plot()
Out[91]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x7f9f3e7c9410>
```

Additionally I want to show marker 'x' for each point. For example, DataFrame df has two row so that I want to mark 'x' or 'o' for each point on the graph.

**Updated:**

After applied Ffisegydd's great solution, I got the following graph which I originally want.

```
In [6]: df.plot(ylim=(0,1), marker='x')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pandas.DataFrame.plot()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) will return a matplotlib axes object. This can be used to modify things like the y-limits using `ax.set_ylim()`.

Alternatively, when you call `df.plot()` you can pass in arguments for the style, one of these arguments can be `ylim=(minimum_value, maximum_value)`, meaning you don't have to manually use `ax.set_ylim()` after plotting.

You can also pass extra keyword-arguments that are passed to the matplotlib plotting routine, you can use this to set the marker as `x` with `marker='x'`.

A toy example is given below, where the ylim have been set to `(0,5)` and the marker to `x` in the `df.plot()` call.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':[0,1,2,3,4], 'y':[0,0.5,1,1.5,2]})

ax = df.plot(ylim=(0,5), marker='x')

plt.show()
```

[image: Example plot]

Comment: I didn't know that df.plot with matplotlib parameters. It worked well! Thank you so much.

Comment: @sangheestyle it takes both some custom `pandas` parameters and also `matplotlib` params, I'd suggest reading the linked docs to see what you can do (it's quite powerful :))

Comment: Yes, I think I need to read it and try some parameters. Their documentation is pretty good!